# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Unobtrusive Ajax Validation Not Working With Partial View Form Swap

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-core-2.1

I've spent several hours combing Stackoverflow and other sites trying everyone's solutions with no luck so far.  I'm sure I've missed something, but I can't see it.  Hopefully you can point me to a fix.

I have an initial form inside a partial view that is rendered into a parent view whose validation works fine.  Once the form is submitted via Ajax replace, I return either a login or registration partial view with a new form in the response.  This second form will not display the model validation errors when an incomplete form is submitted and the same partial view is returned.

Thanks in advance for any tips you can offer to bring an end to this insanity!

### Parent View Section

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" id="formData">
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_UserNamePartial", new UserNameViewModel())
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### Working Rendered Partial View

```
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">Let's Start With Your E-mail Address</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="IsAccountValid" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST"
              data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#formData">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="UserName">Your Email Address</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address" />
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" id="btnGetStarted" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### Initial Validation Controller Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult IsAccountValid(UserNameViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return PartialView("../Home/_UserNamePartial", model);

        AccountRepository accountRepository = new AccountRepository(ConnectionConfig.InshoraDev);
        AuthName match = accountRepository.GetAuthName(model.UserName);

        if (match != null)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            LoginViewModel loginModel = new LoginViewModel()
            {
                UserName = model.UserName
            };

            return PartialView("_UserLoginPartial", loginModel);
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
        SignUpViewModel signupModel = new SignUpViewModel()
        {
            UserName = model.UserName,
        };

        return PartialView("_UserSignUp", signupModel);
    }
```

### Login Partial View (Validation Error Display Not Working)

```
@model Inshora.Models.Account.LoginViewModel

<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Log Into Your Account</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <form id="login-form" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;"
                  data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="formData" data-ajax-complete="AcctLib.Login.Events.onComplete">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="@Model.UserName">
                    <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="RememberMe" id="RememberMe">
                    <label for="RememberMe"> Remember Me</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="Log In">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a id="PasswordReset" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="PasswordReset" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#formData" tabindex="5" class="inshora-forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        AcctLib.Login.Init();
    })
</script>
```

### LoginViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

### Client Side Initialization Code

```
AcctLib.Login.RebindForm = function() {
    $('form').each(function (i, f) {
        $form = $(f);
        $form.removeData('validator');
        $form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
    });
}

AcctLib.Login.Init = function () {
    AcctLib.Login.RebindForm();
    $('#UserName').focus();
}
```

## Update

I have updated the parent page (index.cshtml) to the following and it still doesn't display the messages.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" id="formData">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_UserNamePartial", new UserNameViewModel())
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Comment: Lastly where do you have the partial defined to inject the `_ValidationScriptsPartial`? or are you rolling your own grown validation?

Comment: I'm using _Layout.cshtml to include the validation scripts:

        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js">

Comment: That might be part of the problem... I only use validation with in the partial within `@section Scripts{}`, because now validation is active all the time when in _layout

Comment: Thanks.  This is my first core mvc app after doing quite a few MVC 4 apps.  I wasn't aware of the new _ValidationScriptsPartial.  I modified the index page to include this in the scripts section.  The initial partial view validates just fine.  The ajax loaded form still doesn't show the validation errors.  I guess I'd better start walking through the unobtrusive source code to see what I'm missing.

Comment: You should be re-parsing the `$.validator` in the `success` callback of your ajax call that is loading the form (after the partial has been added to the DOM). And scripts should never be in partial views.

Comment: I figured out the issue.  I wasn't using the tag helpers for model binding which didn't generate the data-val="true" for each control to be validate.  Thus the unobtrusive validation skipped them since they weren't marked for validation!  Another case of RTFM!!

Comment: Thanks @mvermef for giving me some prompts that led me to the right solution.

Comment: Glad it moved you in right direction

Comment: user3559349 indicated that the '$.validator' needs to be "re-parsed" in the success callback. I have exactly the same issue. But how do I re"parse" the validator in the success callback? Just copying the line, which I call directly in the JS, to the success body of the ajax call, does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I had not used the asp-for tag helpers. Those helpers are responsible for generating the data-* attributes needed by the unobtrusive validation parser.  Once I started using them it started working.  Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

## Corrected View

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <form id="login-form" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post" role="form"
                  data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#formData">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="UserName"></label>
                    <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                    <label asp-for="RememberMe"> Remember Me</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="Log In">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a id="PasswordReset" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="PasswordReset" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#formData" tabindex="5" class="inshora-forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction @StephenMuecke.  Do I just click "Add Another Answer" to add the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   return PartialView("..\\Home\\_UserNamePartial", model);
```

pretty sure this violates pathing

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
   return PartialView("../Home/_UserNamePartial", model);
```

Comment: Thanks for notice that. I updated the code.  Still searching for the fix to error display.

Answer (score -1):

Cut renderPartial link and paste to before @script section, like below:

```
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }

@section Scripts
{

}
```